# Closed form for $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)\tan^{-1}(x)}{e^x-1} \, dx$? (Closed)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Recently I have tried the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}H_x \ln(x) \, dx,$$
where $H_x$ denotes the harmonic number.

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}H_x\ln(x) \, dx &= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\ln(x)\frac{1-t^x}{1-t} \, dx\,dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1}\left(-\gamma\frac{\pi}{2}+\left(\gamma+\ln(1+\ln^2(t) \right )\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\ln(t)} \right ) \right )\frac{dt}{1-t} \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\tan^{-1}(\ln(t))+\ln(1+\ln^2(t))\cot^{-1}(\ln(t))}{1-t} \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}(t)}{e^t-1} \, dt - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+t^2)\cot^{-1}(t)}{e^t-1}\, dt.
\end{align*}

And now I'm completely struggling to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+t^2)\cot^{-1}(t)}{e^t-1}\, dt.$$

(EDIT) Here my approach ,
Consider The Hermite's Hurwitz zeta function representation given by
$ \zeta (s, q) = \frac 1 {2 q^s} + \frac { q^{1 - s} } {s - 1} + 2 \int_0^\infty \frac { \sin (s \arctan (\frac{x}{q}) ) } { (q^2 + x^2)^{\frac{ s}{2}}  (e^{2 \pi x} - 1) } d x =\frac 1 {2 q^s} + \frac { q^{1 - s} } {s - 1} + 4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac { \sin (s \arctan (\frac{x}{2\pi q}) ) } { ((2\pi q)^2 + x^2)^{\frac{ s}{2}}  (e^{x} - 1) } d x$.
From here , let $q=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ , we get ,
$\zeta (s, \frac{1}{2\pi})=\frac{(2\pi)^s}{2} + \frac { (2\pi)^{s-1} } {s - 1} + 4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac { \sin (s \arctan (x) ) } { (1 + x^2)^{\frac{ s}{2}}  (e^{x} - 1) } d x$.

Noticing that $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial s^2} \frac{\sin(s \tan^{-1}(x))}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}}\right ) = - \tan^{-1}(x)\ln(1+x^2)$. Let's derive from s twice , we get :
$-\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{e^x-1} \, dx = \frac{\zeta^{(2,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{2\pi} \right )}{4\pi}-\frac{\ln^2(2\pi)}{8\pi}+\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\left(2+2\ln(2\pi)+\ln^2(2\pi) \right )$

Comment: Is there a reason to believe a closed form exists?

Comment: Its alright i found the value of the integral

Comment: Then, please, give the steps and answer